# How to open ringtone preference in react native app

Tags: react-native

How to open ringtone preference setting menu in android using react native?

I have checked react-native-ringtone-manager but it's not working well. Any possible solution or any npm libraries is available for this.

Comment: Is this to change the ringtone in the phone itself or only in your app?

Comment: Actually, it's an alarm app. Need to change the alarm tone from the phone settings. It's ok to change the tone of the phone iteself.